# Insert admin user on first boot

Tags: c#, blazor

I am creating a Blazor app with basic authentication.
The problem is the following: When I launch the application, I cannot access anything, I am not connected (registration is only done via a user who has the right). So I want to create an admin: admin account when the database is initialized.

Here is what I did:
**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserManager<T_Utilisateur> _userManager){
    ...
    app.InitBaseDeDonnes(Configuration["DefaultApplicativePassword"], _userManager);
    ...
}
```

**InitData.cs**

```
public async static void InitBaseDeDonnes(this IApplicationBuilder _app, string _defaultPassword, UserManager<T_Utilisateur> _userManager){
    ...
    await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "admin");
    ...
}
```

But here is the error that returned to me (about the "_userManager" object) :

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
```

Do you know which method should I use to create this admin user?

Comment: Obviously, you need a login page that doesn't require a user to be logged in.  If the user is not authenticated, then it should automatically go to the login / registration page.  Once you have created a user, you can add the "Admin" role by hand in your database.

Comment: Thank you for this method, but it does not meet the customer's request: /

Comment: I don't know what your data layer is, and this is a data layer issue.  In your main layout page's `OnInitialized` method, you can check if there's any user with the `Admin` role, and if there isn't, add one.

Comment: I seed the initial user via the appsettings.json preferably using a secrets vault in startup.cs in the configure method, at this stage the services are available. That way the credentials can be removed/customized easily and not hard coded.

Comment: In this app I seed users with various roles. It is demo app. In production I would source the credentials and roles as I said above from settings to remove the hard coding.
https://github.com/BrianLParker/AuthApp/blob/master/AuthApp/Server/Data/ApplicationDbInitialiser.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting the manager from the services is a possibility to access the class allowing this to manage the users. Pass this class from Startup.cs not working.

```
public async static void InitBaseDeDonnes(this IApplicationBuilder _app, string _defaultPassword) {
    ...
    int nbUser = await UtilisateurDal.CountAsync();
    if (nbUser < 1) {
        using (IServiceScope scope = _app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope()) {
            UserManager<T_Utilisateur> userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<T_Utilisateur>>();

            Task.Run(() => InitAdminUser(userManager, "admin@domain.com")).Wait();
        }
    }
    ...
}

private static async Task InitAdminUser(UserManager<T_Utilisateur> _userManager, string _email) {
    T_Utilisateur user = new T_Utilisateur {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        UserName = _email,
        Email = _email,
        EmailConfirmed = true,
        DateDeCreation = DateTime.Now,
        SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    };

    await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Constants.MotDePasseDefaut);
}
```

Comment: Do not post just the code. Explain how your answer solves the problem